# Calculated Column IF MsLists

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, microsoft-lists

I'm trying to move one of our old spreadsheets onto MS Lists. There is a formula in there which is:

```
=IF(AND(E2=0),"0",IF(AND(E2>=6.5,E2<=8),1,2))
```

I've tried a few variations through the forums on here and can't spot what I might be doing wrong.

At the moment I am trying:

```
=if([pH]="0")
    , "0"
    , if([pH]<="6.4"
         , "1"
         , if([pH]>="6.5"
              , "2"
             )
         )
    )
```

But not having much luck! any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Number column for `[pH]` and below formula for calculated column:

```
=IF([pH]=0,"0",IF([pH]<=6.4,"1",IF([pH]>=6.5,"2","")))
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

If `[pH]` is "Single line of text" column, use:

```
=IF(Value([pH])=0,"0",IF(Value([pH])<=6.4,"1",IF(Value([pH])>=6.5,"2","")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this formula:

```
=IF([pH]="0","0",IF(AND([pH]>="6.5",[pH]<="8"),"1","2"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.